# how to add static column which does not exists in SQL database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a select query which shows up 2 columns (file type and location ), I want one more column (Region) which does not exist in the table. Also, this column should contain value based of one of the Location type column.

```
FileType Location Region 
------------------------------

3 25 New York
=============

2 25 New York
=============

1 26 London
=======================================
```

if the location is 25, Region type should show up New York and
If the location is 26, Region type should show up London.

Thanks in advance, I hope someone can help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FileType
   , Location
   , CASE Location WHEN 25 THEN 'New York' WHEN 26 THEN 'London' ELSE NULL END AS Region
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thanks @igor..appreciate your help.

Comment: @rishabhshukla - if this solves your problem please consider marking it as the answer using the checkbox on the left of the answer.